# Reinstalling intero using stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, intero

I deleted intero from `~/Users/amir/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.14/8.0.2/bin/`. Now if i run `stack install intero`. I get the following error:

```
Couldn't find executable intero in directory ~/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.14/8.0.2/bin/
```

Is there any way to force reinstalling? I tried `--force-dirty` as well.

Comment: Can you do a `stack build intero` and/or `stack clean` before.

Comment: Did not work. Still same error. Also running `stack exec -- ghc-pkg unregister --force intero` says: `ghc-pkg: cannot find package intero`.

Comment: I had to manually copy it from `~/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-9.14/8.0.2/bin/intero` to `~/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.14/8.0.2/bin/`. And that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue about this [here](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3083).  Workaround for now is to also do `rm ~/Users/amir/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-9.14/8.0.2/installed-packages/intero-*`